# Pedigree In channel type entry

Tags: craft3, entry-type

I want to create a pedigree for user. I have created a section (channel type) and added some properties like about, name and some other user properties. I also want to add a pedigree for that user but don't know how i can create it. I have added a template UI element and added some input fields where elements name in the following scenario :

```
<input type="text" name="fields[pedigree0]" >

<input type="text" name="fields[pedigree1]" >
<input type="text" name="fields[pedigree2]" >

<input type="text" name="fields[pedigree11]" >
<input type="text" name="fields[pedigree12]" >
.
.
.
```

I have created these pedigree0, pedigree1, pedigree2, pedigree11, pedigree12 in fields where field type in plain text.

I want below type of structure where box are input fields.It is not possible using field drag and drop in section entity type.

Can somebody tell me how i can make custom input box in an entry form in control panel ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather extensive topic and there are multiple ways to solve it. First, are you sure you need that kind of graphical tree diagram for the input field? Because that's gonna be a a bit involved. If you just need to keep track of some relational data, you can use [Relations](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/relations.html) to represent the pedigree, using an [Entries field](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries-fields.html#inline-entry-editing) for the input. Another great option to represent hierarchical data would be to represent your pedigree as a [structure section](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries.html#structures), where each entry is a node in the pedigree. This would give you the graphical hierarchy overview you're looking for as well as drag-and-drop support for arranging pedigrees.

If none of that matches your use case, you might have to register the pedigree input field as a custom [field type](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/field-types.html). Then you have complete control over the way that data is stored and how the input is presented to the user. That's gonna be a lot of work though, so make sure you can't use one of the simple solutions mentioned above.